# Proving that there are only finitely many distinct groups G.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Prove that there are only finitely many distinct groups G on the n-element set {$0,1,2,....,n-1$}, i.e., there are only finitely many Cayley tables for the set {$0,1,2,...,n-1$}. Provide some upper bound, as a function of n, on the number of such group.

I have no idea where to start this problem at all. Can anyone give me any sort of hints/clues to lead me in the right direction?

Comment: Broad hint: what does a Cayley table for the set $\{0\ldots n-1\}$ look like?  What are the _simplest_ constraints on the numbers in such a table? You might start by considering the rows of the table; how many different possibilities are there for each row? How can you use that to bound the total number of different possibilities?  (Hint 2: if there are $x$ possibilities for each of $n$ rows, then the total number of possibilities is...?)

Answer (score 4):

Cayley's theorem tells you that every group $G$ with $n$ elements is (isomorphic to) a subgroup of $S_n$, which has $n!$ elements. Thus there can be at most $\binom{n!}{n}$ groups on $n$ elements.

Another possible argument is given by looking at the multiplication table of the group. There are $n^{(n^2)}$ ways to fill it, and thus at most that many groups on $n$ elements. For a more precise bound, notice that every line/row must contain every element of the group exactly once (i.e. the multiplication by a fixed element of the group is transitive), so you get easily to the better bound $(n!)^n$.

I am certain that it is possible to find even better bounds, but it probably requires a bit more work.

Answer (score 3):

If $|G| = n$, then the group is determined by the product map $f_a(b) = ab$ for each $a$ in the group. For each $a$, the product map $f_a$ gives a permutation of the elements of $G$ (because if $ab = ac$ in a group then $b=c$). So you have at most $n!$ choices for each product map $f_a$, giving a loose bound of $(n!)^n$ on the number of possible groups with elements $\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$. Almost certainly, much better bounds are possible.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the Cayley table has $n^2$ squares.  For each square, it must be filled with an element from an $n$-element set.  You can use this to get an upper bound.  It may not be a great upper bound, but you only asked for "some upper bound".