# Prove that there exists finitely many groups of order n.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism

Every finite group is isomorphic to some permutation group.

Any group of order $n$ can be embedded into $S_n$.

(We say that group $G_1$ is embedded into $G_2$ if there is $f:G_1\to G_2$ that is homomorphism and injective.)

Now using this theorem we need to prove that there exists finitely many groups of order n.

My work.

Because every finite group  of order $n$ can be embedded into $S_n$ and number of permutations is $n!$ so number of groups of order $n$ is $\leq \binom{n!}{n}$. Is this right? If yes how show it is always strictly less.

Sorry if this is very simple question.

The similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497888/proving-that-there-are-only-finitely-many-distinct-groups-g) says the same thing I am saying that there are at most $ \binom{n!}{n}$ possibilities. Question is why it can't be exactly $ \binom{n!}{n}$ but is strictly less than that.

Comment: @Sampah I edited my post

Comment: I think that there are infinitely many groups of order 1. Every singleton set is uniquely the underlying set of a group with the single element being the identity of the group. Of course, all such groups of order 1 are isomorphic to each other.

Comment: Without using any theorems, it is clear that a group structure for a set with $n$ elements is determined by an ordering of its elements and the multiplication table, which is a $n\times n$ matrix (with some properties). Since there are only finitely many orderings and matrices, there are only finitely many groups.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning isn't enough: why is it not the case that there are infinitely many groups of order $4$? You've said all such groups are isomorphic to permutation groups, but why can't there be a group of order $4$ isomorphic to $S_{100}$? You're using the symbol $n$ to denote at least two possibly-different numbers.

You're going to need some stronger property of the permutation groups; presumably your proof of that theorem actually gives you a lot more information than you've stated.

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: Why it can't be exactly $\binom{n!}{n}$

Comment: Why do you think it can't be? What about $n=2$?